# How to get Children's keys to a listview without below values in firebase database android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the sample database
[image of the data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAFJa.jpg)

Hello I'm a beginner in firebase and android studio. I want to get the client_id's key names without its sub keys and values.

For example

098798788

343243209

348987206

My code shows key names but it repeats the same key.
here is my code:

```
//list view code start ----------------------------------------------------------------;

    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview00);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,usernames);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("clients/client_id");

    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {




            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String  value = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                usernames.add(value);
            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    //list view code end----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
  ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview00);
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("clients").child("client_id");

myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {




        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            String  value = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            usernames.add(value);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,usernames);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```